# Why am I getting a type error in this LeetCode solution?

Tags: java, arraylist

For my solution in Leetcode, I am getting the following error. The question is : https://leetcode.com/problems/kids-with-the-greatest-number-of-candies/

Error :

```
Line 15: error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to List<Boolean>
                return result.add(false);
                                 ^
Line 18: error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to List<Boolean>
                return result.add(true);
                                 ^
2 errors
```

My code:

```
class Solution {
public List<Boolean> kidsWithCandies(int[] candies, int extraCandies) {
    
    List<Boolean> result = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    int max = 0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<candies.length; i++) {
        if(candies[i] > max) {
            candies[i] = max;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<candies.length; i++) {
        if(candies[i] + extraCandies > max) {
            return result.add(false);
        }
        else {
            return result.add(true);
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: Please add a suitable tag for the language you're using. (I strongly suspect it's Java, but we shouldn't have to guess.)

Comment: Next, to understand the error itself: what do you expect the value returned by `result.add(false)` to be? What does the documentation say the return type of `List<E>.add()` is? Are you sure you want to return immediately on the first iteration of your second `for` loop? (I suspect you don't.)

Comment: Thank you, i got it! i need to remove the return tags as i want it to return at the end of the loop!

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `return` before the `result.add(...)`. Otherwise, you try to return the value you just added to the list, instead of returning the list itself like you want.

Comment: Got it, Thank you so much!